# React Map Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a react App, but the map function in the below code snippet is throwing me `this.props.books.map` is not a function error. I've included all the corresponding codes.

I've checked the console log and the value getting printed is an empty array? Why is it happening?

I've checked the `res.data` at the dispatch function, but it's fine there.

```
class Books extends Component{

static getDerivedStateFromProps = props => {
        props.getBookInfo();
        console.log(props.books)
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <Container>
            <Styles>
                <Row>
                    {
                    this.props.books.map((book) => {
                        return(
                        .
                        .
                        )
                </Row>
            </Styles>
            </Container>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    books: state.books
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getBookInfo })(Books);
```

getBookInfo

```
export const getBookInfo = () => dispatch =>{
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/books")
        .then( (res) => {
            return {
                type: BOOK_INFO,
                payload: res.data
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => dispatch({
            type: GET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.data
        }))
}
```

bookReducer

```
const initalState={};

export default function(state=initalState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case BOOK_INFO:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }    
}
```

This is what I'm getting if I `console.log` `res.data`

```
Array(3)
0: {name: "Harry Potter", author: "J.K. Rowling", price: "150", year: "2011", description: "No wear and tear excellent condition.", …}
1: {name: "One Punch Man", author: "Yusuke Murata", price: "150", year: "2009", description: "Buy the damn thing.", …}
2: {name: "Percy Jackson", author: "Rick Riordan", price: "150", year: "2015", description: "Cool.", …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: What's `this.props.books`? Where is the constructor initializing `this.props`?

Comment: doesn't ```this.props.books``` gets mapped from the connect() function.

Comment: Is the error regarding `this.props.map` as you say in the question or `this.props.books.map`, which is the only `map` in the code?

Comment: It's ```this.props.books.map``` I've edited the question

Answer (score 0):

your initial state is an empty object and not an empty array and therefore cant be `map`ped at init render

Comment: Thanks for the answer can you give more detail on what you mean by ```res``` to JSON?

Comment: So changing initialState fixed the error but ```this.props.books``` is returning an empty array and nothing is being rendered.

Comment: can you provide `console.log` inside the reducer just before the `return`?

Comment: It's look like your second issue connected to the usage of `return` instead of `dispatch` in the action, put `console.log` inside the reducer to see if it indeed not fired

Comment: Yes, I finally got it working. The error was using ```return``` instead of ```dispatch```.